# Refreshing eclipse-project at the end of a maven build

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2, maven-3, m2e

Is there a possibility to refresh the files and folders of a project within eclipse at the end of a maven build automatically.
Usually I'm building from commandline. After a build e. g. the target folder should be refreshed.

Additional info: the maven build runs in the command line and eclipse should update automatically when it ended.

Comment: Are you satisfied with the answer?

Comment: As I wrote I'm building mostly from commandline. Therefore I'm searching for a suitable solution for commandline triggered builds. Your answer is helpful but not exact what I want. So I can't accept your answer, sorry. Maybe, somebody else has written an eclipse plugin for that problem.

Comment: I have the plugin. It uses a socket to communicate with eclipse so a single exec rule in the pom.xml can be used to trigger it. I would highly appreciate you putting a bounty on this question. :)

Comment: I added the project to the answer.

Comment: Have you seen the answer?

Comment: Thanks for starting the bounty. If you can award it, then I'm happy to receive. Create an issue if you encounter problems with the plugin. But it's simple as a brick so pretty easy to conceive. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use Run as -> Maven build... In the run configuration/build properties go to the refresh tab and select the refresh option you want.

Note that *the eclipse build and the maven build may interfere*, so make sure that you turn off the `Build automatically` option in the Project menu before staring the maven build. You may get indeterministic compilation errors otherwise.

[image]

Here is an eclipse plugin that implements the external hook for refreshing: https://github.com/andrask/maven-eclipse-control-plugin

Comment: Refresh using hooks or polling doesn't refresh immediatelly.

Comment: That helps for building via eclipse. But I'm searching for a solution for building via commandline.

Comment: You can run the maven build from Eclipse this way. Right click on the project, Run as -> Maven build... This effectively runs the `mvn` comm and inside your eclipse and depending on the launcher you set up, the workspace will be refreshed. Only the native hooks and refresh on access are your other options. It is impossible to make eclipse know about a command line build otherwise.

Comment: So in short what you are looking for is not supported. But if you run inside eclipse, all works as I described.

Comment: Your answer is not exact what I'm looking for but the best hint till now.

Comment: Sorry but what you are looking for doesn't exist. Running a maven build inside eclipse is the same as it would happen in the command line. If you still decide to do it from the command line, then refreshing needs to be done manually. There will be no better answer until you create a an eclipse plugin for that. But if you reading up your question again, I think I answered exactly what you were asking.

Comment: Good answer, helped me to do what I wanted. Thans and upvote!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so, there is no option to link the two things.

But eclipse has an option `Refresh on access` which might be useful for you.

Comment: Refresh on access doesn't refresh the target folder if I build from commandline.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the accepted answer of using Run as -> Maven build... and the Refresh option did not refresh the target folder in Eclipse.  I needed to do the following:

Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Refresh using native hooks or polling

When enabled, any changes made by external editors will be automatically discovered by the Workbench.  On some systems there may be a slight delay if polling is used.